# How to write code more beatify and can speed up program in my case?

Tags: python

I have a class "DataProcessing" is for processing with dataframe "df".

With processing df have some step like this:

First, get dataframe "df" from csv file.

Second, concat df and constant df.

Third,  calculate some indicators with df.

Fourth, judge strategy with df data.

Fifth, multiprocessing fourth step.

Here is the code I write just using a function "data_processing":

```
class DataProcessing:
    def __init__(self, constant_df):
        self.constant_df = constant_df 

    # First, get dataframe "df" from csv file. 
    def data_processing(self, code):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(...)

        # Second, concat df and constant df.
        self.df = pd.concat([self.df, self.constant_df]) # Should I naming a new variable?

        # Third,  calculate some indicators with df. 
        self.df = do some calculating...

        # Fourth, judge strategy with df data. 
        if self.df do some judge...

    # Fifth, multiprocessing fourth step.
    def multiprocessing(self, code):
        # use multiprocessing Pool...
```

or I can use multiple functions like this

```
class DataProcessing: 
    def __init__(self, constant_df):
        self.constant_df = constant_df 

    # First, get dataframe "df" from csv file. 
    def get_df(self, code):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(...)
        return 

    # Second, concat df and constant df.
    def concat_df(self, code):
        self.get_df(code) # Need run get_df function to get self.df first 
        self.df = pd.concat([self.df, self.constant_df])
        return 
    
    # Third,  calculate some indicators with df. 
    def calculate_indicators(self, code):
        self.concat_df(code) # Need run concat_df function to get self.df that concated 

    # Fourth, judge strategy with df data. 
    def judge_strateg(self, code):
        self.calculate_indicators(code) # Need run calculate_indicators function first 
        if ... # do some judge 

    # Fifth, multiprocessing fourth step.
    def multiprocessing(self):
        # use multiprocessing Pool...
```

But if I use multiple functions, I need to run the previous function in the function first and pass the same arg "code",
that makes me doubt is there have another way to write code beautiful?

Thanks

Comment: Here is PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python, hope it helps: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0):

Why not saving the code as a instance variable?

```
    def __init__(self, constant_df, code):
        self.constant_df = constant_df 
        self.code = code
... 
    def judge_strateg(self):
        self.calculate_indicators(self.code)    # use it there
```

or you have a overall-fuction that does it all (if for some not obvious reason you don't want to have code as a instance variable)

```
    def __init__(self, constant_df):
        self.constant_df = constant_df 

    # Overall
    def process_all(self, code):
        df.self = get_df()
        df.self = concat_df()
        #...
        df.self = calculate_indicators(self, code)
        #...

    # First, get dataframe "df" from csv file. 
    def get_df(self):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(...)
        return 

    # Second, concat df and constant df.
    def concat_df(self):
        self.get_df(code) # Need run get_df function to get self.df first 
        self.df = pd.concat([self.df, self.constant_df])
        return 
    
    # Third,  calculate some indicators with df. 
    def calculate_indicators(self, code):
        self.concat_df(code) # Need run concat_df function to get self.df that concated 

    # Fourth, judge strategy with df data. 
    def judge_strateg(self, code):
        self.calculate_indicators(code) # Need run calculate_indicators function first 
        if ... # do some judge 

    # Fifth, multiprocessing fourth step.
    def multiprocessing(self):
        # use multiprocessing Pool...
```

splitting up your code is definitely a goo idea. but passing a variable not

Comment: because the code is in a code_list, and code_list is for multiprocessing  Pool map used. So that can't be a instance variable.

Comment: But have a overall-function that does it all is a good idea, I will think about it, thanks.